# Grommet UI how to modify the size of the components?

Tags: reactjs, themes, grommet

I try to use the components from the Grommet UI with ReactJs.
I would like to understand if there is a way to use an existing Grommet theme in order to have smaller components (text input, number input, datetime) or I have to customize by overriding the components dimentions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No grommet supported way.

Yeah there is not a easy way to reduce the components size.
Just some containers and icons have the attribute `size` that can have a shirt-sized dimension `xsmall small medium large etc.`

But if it is of help I found handy to modify the size through styles:

```
<GrommetComponent style={{width:'100%', height:20}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, the proposition works. Just one small problem with the svg is used as for the select fileds.

Comment: In addition to the "shirt sizes" some components can handle a 'string' prop, which can be something like '222px' or other CSS size.

Answer (score 1):

Create Template component for each different element and set properties as needed in template. For example, below component set the height of the button by passing props.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from 'grommet';

export const Button = styled(BaseButton)`

${props => props.height && `
    height: ${props.height};
`}
`;
```

And in new component import it and pass props as needed:

```
<Button secondary fill height="auto" type="submit">
 Log In
</Button>
```